# CakePhp render a blank view

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a CakePHP application where all the view works, but two.
This is the controller:

```
 <?php
    App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
    class CardsController extends AppController {
      public function index() {
      } 
    }
    ?>
```

And this is the view

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Card', array(
'url' => array(
    'controller' => 'cards',
    'action' => 'view'
)
));
echo $this->Form->input('codice');
echo $this->Form->end('Cerca');*/
?>
```

Checking with the firefox console I got this:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

The "view" view, called by the form has the same problem.
Normally if the view is missing Cake return an error, in this case if I delete the index.ctp the result is in any case a blank page.
I can't find what the problem is.

**UPDATE 1**
My route code:

```
<?php
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
CakePlugin::routes();
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
?>
```

**UPDATE 2 **
My folder structure

```
├── Config
│   └── Schema
├── Console
│   ├── Command
│   └── Templates
├── Controller
│   ├── ()
│   ├── Component
│   ├── docs
│   └── output
├── files
├── Lib
├── Locale
│   └── eng
├── Model
│   ├── ()
│   ├── Behavior
│   └── Datasource
├── Plugin
│   ├── AclExtras
│   ├── CakePdf
│   └── DebugKit
├── Test
│   ├── Case
│   └── Fixture
├── tmp
│   ├── cache
│   └── logs
├── Vendor
│   └── tcpdf
├── View
│   ├── ()
│   ├── Cards
│   ├── Clientis
│   ├── Elements
│   ├── Emails
│   ├── Errors
│   ├── Fornitoris
│   ├── Groups
│   ├── Helper
│   ├── Indirizzos
│   ├── Layouts
│   ├── Magsits
│   ├── Movimentis
│   ├── Pagamentos
│   ├── Pages
│   ├── Pdcard
│   ├── Pdf
│   ├── Posts
│   ├── Rdocumentos
│   ├── Rlistinos
│   ├── Scaffolds
│   ├── Storicotransaziones
│   ├── Tdocumentos
│   ├── Titoliviaggios
│   ├── Tmovimentis
│   ├── Users
│   ├── Verificas
│   ├── Voucher
│   └── Widgets
└── webroot
    ├── css
    ├── files
    ├── images
    ├── img
    └── js
```

**UPDATE 3**
Card model

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model', 'AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
class Card extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Packet' => array('foreignKey' => 'pacchetto'), 'Tdocumento' => array('foreignKey' => 'iddocument'));
    public $hasMany = array('Visit' => array('foreignKey' => 'codicecarta'));
    public $primaryKey = 'codicecarta';

    public function afterFind($results, $primary = true) {
        for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($results); $i++) { 
            if($results[$i]['Card']['minore'] == 1){
                $results[$i]['Card']['minore'] = 'Yes';
            }else{
                $results[$i]['Card']['minore'] = 'No';
            }
            if($results[$i]['Card']['gratuito'] == 1){
                $results[$i]['Card']['gratuito'] = 'Yes';
            }else{
                $results[$i]['Card']['gratuito'] = 'No';
            }
            $datavalidita = $this->formatodata($results[$i]['Card']['iniziovalidita']);
            $datavisita = $this->formatodata($results[$i]['Card']['dataprenotazione']);
            $results[$i]['Card']['datainizio'] = $datavalidita[0];
            $results[$i]['Card']['orainizio'] = $datavalidita[1];
            $results[$i]['Card']['datavisita'] = $datavisita[0];
            $results[$i]['Card']['oravisita'] = $datavisita[1];
        }
        return $results;
    }

    public $validate = array(
        'nominativo' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A username is required'
            )
        ),
        'codicecarta'=> array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Inserire il codice'
            )
        )
    );
    private function formatodata($dataora){
        $dataora = explode(' ', $dataora);
        $data = $dataora[0]; 
        $data = date('d-m-y', strtotime($data));
        $ora = $dataora[1]; 
        $ora = substr($ora, 0,5);
        return array($data, $ora);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 4**
My View/Layout/default.ctp

```
<html>
<head> 
    <?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>
    <title>
        <?php echo $cakeDescription ?>:
        <?php echo $title_for_layout; ?>
    </title>
    <?php
        echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
        echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
        echo $this->fetch('meta');
        echo $this->fetch('css');
        echo $this->fetch('script');?>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1><?php echo $this->Html->link($cakeDescription, 'http://cakephp.org'); ?></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
            <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>  
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your view code, you have a comment fragment left: `*/` (after the last echo). I think this throws a php error and the error is not displayed, maybe because of debug level in `core.php`.

Comment: Sorry, there is in the post but not in the code

Comment: Post your Folder structure in Controller , Model and View here by Editing question

Comment: Hello @Tres , I mean show `Your` folders , files too :) . I cant see Cards folder in your view , no CardsController.php ! comeon ..

Comment: Clean your model first like my answer , and check if it works

Comment: I mean show Your folders , files too :) . I cant see Cards folder in your view , no CardsController.php ! comeon ..

Comment: set DEBUG On , by setting `Configure::write('debug',1);`

Comment: Set ->  Configure::write('debug',1);

Comment: I put in my index function inside card controller  Configure::write('debug',1);but still all the debug, echo etc aren't visible

Comment: I Hope your default.ctp or A layout you use has this line , if not , add it ->  `echo $this->element('sql_dump'); `

Comment: Yep, I edit the question with the default.ctp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71010/discussion-between-tres-and-jquery-php-magento-com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was sneaky, in the controller, before the php tag there was an empty line. That line broke the flow of the dispatcher of the controller.

Comment: Please explain properly.

Comment: And you didnt paste Empty line in your Question :)

Comment: No, probably I delete it while indenting on the editor of stackoverflow :(

Answer (score 1):

Create `Cards` folder in your View folder and add there index.ctp. You may be missing Folder structure which is convention in cakephp.

Remove `*/` from your code.

I recommand you to create elements like header.ctp, footer.ctp

And use default.ctp for normal usage like this which will include your header , footer and view content.

```
<html>

<?php echo $this->element('head'); ?>
<body>


    <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); 
          echo $this->Html->script('additional-methods');           
    ?>

    <div class="footerVersion" style="float: left;
width: 100%;text-align: center;">
        Version : <?php echo VERSION_NUMBER;?>
    </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Make sure you have routs.php like this.

```
<?php    
    //Goto login page if base url is called.
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'));  
/**
 * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's urls.
 */
    Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

/**
 * Load all plugin routes. See the CakePlugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
    CakePlugin::routes();

/**
 * Load the CakePHP default routes. Only remove this if you do not want to use
 * the built-in default routes.
 */
    require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

An ideal model should look like this :

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Card extends AppModel {
}
?>
```

Comment: There is already, but if I delete the folder, or the ctp inside the folder, still no error, only blank page. Also with the correct folder and that ctp file I get a blank page

Comment: Do you have any routes configured? Maybe check if index function is called with a simple `debug("test"); exit;` (inside your controller function).

Comment: Yes do as per q0re .  Put `echo "in Controller function";`  in your controller's index.php and in  index.ctp , use `echo "in View";`

Comment: I use debug, Debugger::dump and echo both in controller and view, but still blank page. The view doesn't display html code and neither php code, and checking with the console I have empty body tag.  
Yes, I have a route, just redirect "/" to login controller

Comment: then your controller funtion never get called. Check your routes.

Comment: if the url is localhost/oss/ then the login controller is called, but in this case the url is localhost/oss/cards

Comment: @Tres Hope you have Controller named  -> `CardsController.php` and Model `Card.php`

Comment: Do you have configured your webservers mod_rewrite and do you have load mod_rewrite module etc.?

Comment: Yep, I have those name. With the Uppercase localhost/oss/Cards the result is the same. Also all the other URL have no Uppercase letter but works

Comment: If any other controller actions are working, then i think you have a syntax or database error in model/ controller or associated models. Post your model please.

Comment: Now I edit with the model, but this model is used also in another controller (with $this->loadModel('Card'); ), with no error

Comment: @Tres now I hope your database Table naming conventions are ok . Table name is cards.

Comment: Why do u need ` 'AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component'` in Model on 1st line ?

Comment: Probably is a typo, by the way I change the model with yours, but still the same. The strange thing is that I have error only if the controller is missing and not if the model or the view is missing. Normally I have errors in all this cases